# Слайдинг viewpager при вызове setCurrentItem

Tags: android-viewpager, android, sliding

Проблема заключается в следующем: при переходе, допустим, с первого фрагмента ViewPager на 30, происходит плавный слайдинг, но при слайдинге отображаются только те фрагменты, которые хранятся в памяти. То есть у меня установлено setOffscreenPageLimit(1) и я вижу сначала один фрагмент справа от страницы с которой перехожу, потом просто фон, потом уже фрагмент, находящийся слева от страницы на которую перехожу. Собственно вопрос: можно ли убрать прокрутку всех этих страниц ViewPager, чтобы пользователь не видел пустого фона. Хранить все страницы в памяти не решение, так же как и сделать задержку на анимацию перелистывания минимальной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
```

Comment: Спасибо за этот вариант, но анимация все-таки нужна. Может, как то можно реализовать чтобы переход был как бы на следующую страницу, а не через все пролетал слайдинг?